# Spring ConditionalOnBean does not detect bean of type RestController

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I have Spring boot app and I create my own autoconfiguration that should create bean in case any RestController in present in the context.

It looks something like that:

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ConditionalOnBean(RestController.class)
public class MyCustomAutoConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean(){
    // code to create my bean
  }
}
```

I did defined class annotated with `@RestController` and I it works when I access it .
But my AutoConfiguration doesn't kick in . I get the following:

> condition":"OnBeanCondition","message":"@ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController"}],"matched":[]}

As far as I know Autoconfiguration is done AFTER component scanning detected bean of type restcontroller..so why it didn't pick mine?

Comment: If you annotate your controller class with `@RestController` it doesn't mean it's the bean of type `RestController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@CodnitionalOnBean` checks that the bean of provided class is present in the current `ApplicationContext`. If you annotate any class, say class `ABC`, with `@RestController` or whatever annotation you want, the original class of the bean will be `ABC` (I say original because likely spring will wrap you bean with some Proxy, which is completely another topic), so the condition inside the `@CodnitionalOnBean` is not satisfied.

If you need to create some configuration beans in case you have a specific controller, then just annotate this configuration class with `@CodnitionalOnBean(<YOUR CONTROLLER CLASS NAME, NOT THE ANNOTATION NAME>.class)`

Comment: Thanx. So I can I detected if any class is annotated with @RestController within mu autoconfiguration file?

Comment: You can ask `ApplicationContext` to do it, just use `ApplicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(RestController.class)`